# Show that had a pentagram and a frog leaping in slow motion in the opening and a girl getting trapped in a mirror

Tags: story-identification, tv

[image: What the show's frog scene in OP looked like, kinda]

OK, so back around 2010-early 2012, I remember this show coming on that kinda would give me bad vibes.

Like its opening had a pentagram (I think) and this weird music. But the biggest thing I remember about the show's opening is that it had a frog leaping in slow motion in it, similar to this post's picture (barring the watermark of course).

I do not remember much about the show itself, I think it was for teens and maybe had a gothy/witchy flair to it. Anyway, the only thing I remember plotwise is that a girl somehow got trapped in a mirror and her friends got her out.

I think it came on the CW, but maybe it was Fox or another channel. It came on at around 11AM-1PM (may have been rerun time). Like I said earlier, I think it was rated for teens. Also it should be noted that this was on 'free TV' not cable or satellite.

I have been looking for this show a while now, like 4-5 years.

TLDR:

- Aired around 2010-2012 (so no shows older than that), may have came out before then though
- Had a pentagram and a frog leaping in slow motion in the opening, along side 'off'/edgy?/darkish music
- Probably played on CW or Fox, though not certain
- For teen audience I think, probably goths/witches/supernatural-lovers
- Ran around 10AM-1PM, not certain exactly when

It is not:

- *The Secret Circle* (opening is too short, needs to be at least 30 seconds, no frog leaping as well)
- *Charmed* (opening is nothing like what I describe, and did not come on 'free TV' around then)
- *Millennia* (Opening is nothing alike and no girl in mirror apparently)

Comment: Was this live action, or animated?

Comment: Live Action. @Showsni

Comment: This is a ridiculously long shot, but I can see you've had no luck for a long time. Is there any chance you're mixing up your memory of the plot from one show with the [opening credts from True Blood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxINMuOgAu8)? It has a snake (not frog) leaping in slow motion (at 00:24) and frog being caught in a venus fly trap (at 01:03). It has the right date, vibes and music style, but the wrong channel and no pentagram. It's a complete miss on the story you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them has a frog or pentagram in the opening sequence but is there a chance of it being "Penny Dreadful" or "Hemlock Grove"?

EDIT as recommended: the vibe, the genre, the music description, the time seem to remind me of these shows :)

Comment: Why do you feel they match?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots the vibe, the genre, the music description, the time seem to remind me of these shows

Comment: :) Sounds like good things to [edit] into the answer.